# Recursive method in Java is not working. Any ideas?

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I am trying to understand the recursive methods in Java and tried this simple method to calculate a factorial.
Somehow it doesn't work. Can someone tell me why?

```
public class FactorialRecursive extends ConsoleProgram {

   public void run() {
      println("This program calculates the factorial of an integer n.");
      int n = readInt("Please insert n: ");
      int result = factorial(n);
      println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + result);
   }

   private int factorial(int n) {
      int total;
      if (n == 1) total = 1;
      total = n * factorial(n - 1);
      return (total);
   }
}
```

Comment: as soon as it gets down to n == 1 you should return otherwise you still go into factorial and never come out again

Comment: debugging is your friend, you would have found the bug in a minute flat :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is because your base case (`n == 1`) does not return right away.

You only assign `total`, but do not return: instead, you go with `n * factorial(n-1)` again, entering into infinite recursion.

Fix by replacing with

```
if (n==1) return 1;
```

or adding an `else`:

```
if (n==1) total = 1;
else total = n * factorial (n-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not terminating your recursion. Try

```
if (n==1) total = 1;
else total = n * factorial (n-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you dont stop when you find your base case

```
 if (n==1) total = 1;
```

Rather do

```
 if (n==1) return 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line:

```
if (n==1) total = 1;
```

by:

```
if (n==1) return 1;
```

Otherwise, you'll loop infinitely.

Your method would be:

```
private int factorial(int n) {
    return n==1 ? 1 : n * factorial (n-1);
}
```